# Copy data from different excels in one and the same folder

Tags: vba, excel, loops, copy-paste

I want to write a code in VBA, which copies data from different excel sheets, which are all in one folder, to another excel. 
I tried to write an loop, which goes through the different excels in the folder, opens them, copy some content and then pastes it to the end of another excel workbook. For the last step I will have to work with "Dim last as long", but I am not there yet.

There is no defect note, but the macro doesn't do anything.

I am a newbie in VBA and would be very thankful for any advices!

```
 Sub copypaste()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = "L:....xlsx"
    Dim strFileSpec As String: strFileSpec = strFolder & "*.xlsx"
    strFileName = Dir(strFileSpec)
Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open("strFileSpec")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("L:....xlsx")
'Now, transfer values from x to y:
y.Sheets("aaa").Range("C2:BI8").Value = x.Sheets("bbb").Range("A5:BG10")
x.Close
    strFileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: have you stepped through your code using F8 in order to see whether the body of your `Do` loop executes? That seems like an obvious culprit here.

Comment: You may need a value`x.Sheets("bbb").Range("A5:BG10").value` You are also not copying data, you are making 1 range = another range. When doing that, both ranges need to be the same size.`strFolder = "L:....xlsx"` is not a folder name. Check out my sample code to loop through a folder.[Loop Through a folder](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Loop%20Through%20Folder)

Comment: You're also copying in the same destination, so only the *last* set of values would be coped by the above code, provided you work through the problems with your string assignments.

Comment: https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/copy-data-from-one-worksheet-to-another/ among others if you do a web search. Might be worthwhile comparing approaches and limitations.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my solution yet?

Comment: Sorry for my late Response! Yes, I tried it, but it did not work.. I am working on it right now and try to find the mistakes..

Answer (score 0):

If your `Do` loop was executing, your code as given would raise some error(s). Since it's not, I figure your loop isn't executing, which you should have verififed before asking here. If you don't know how, please read Chip Pearson's excellent and brief tutorial about how to debug VBA:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

If your `Do` loop isn't executing, then there's a problem with your folder/file names and/or implementation of the `DIR` function.

`strFolder` for example looks very suspect, because `"L:....xlsx"` doesn't look like a valid *folder* path.

`Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = "L:....xlsx"`

Here's another problem. This line is instructing Excel to open a workbook (within the active directory) named "strFileSpec", this is a string literal, not your variable of similar identifier: `strFileSpec`. Because this line isn't raising an error, the problem is most likely as indicated above (loop not executing), but *this* is also a problem you need to fix:

`Set x = Workbooks.Open("strFileSpec")`

Should be:

`Set x = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)`

And it should be `strFileName` (the result of the `Dir` function) since that's the *source* of your copy/paste.

Further, you should probably be opening `y` outside of the loop, and ensuring that it's a valid filename, which it currently isn't:

`Set y = Workbooks.Open("L:....xlsx")`

So, putting that all together, this:

```
Sub copypaste()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFileSpec As String

    Set y = Workbooks.Open("c:\users\your_name\desktop\file.xlsx") '<< This should be the file path of the file you're copying TO.

    strFolder = "c:\users\your_name\desktop\" '<< make sure this is a valid path to a FOLDER
    strFileSpec = strFolder & "*.xlsx"
    strFileName = Dir(strFileSpec)

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set x = Workbooks.Open("strFileSpec")

        'Now, transfer values from x to y:
        y.Sheets("aaa").Range("C2:BI8").Value = x.Sheets("bbb").Range("A5:BG10")
        x.Close
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

**NOTE** the above just overwrites the same range destination, you'll need to make sure you're writing to a different destination with each iteration of the loop, something like:

```
    Dim i as Long

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set x = Workbooks.Open("strFileSpec")

        'Now, transfer values from x to y:
        With x.Sheets("bbb").Range("A5:BG10")
            y.Sheets("aaa").Range("C2").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Offset(i).Value = .Value
            i = i + .Rows.Count + 1
        End With
        x.Close
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
```